# jQueryUI Drag & Drop compatibility w/ iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a web-based tool that utilizes jQuery UI for drag'n'drop functionality. It works fine across all browsers however, webkit used in iPad and iPhone (and other touch screen smart phones) does not support that functionality. What is the best way to make it compatible with such devices?

Shall I add a script to check for device and if iDevice use different JS library? Or are there any scripts that make jQuery compatible?

Thanks.

Comment: If someone could develop a plug-in to expand jQuery in order to make it 100% compatible with mobile devices (mainly drag'n'drop I suppose) that would be SUPER COOL! A clear need for such bridge. I'd be willing to buy it or gift all my StackIOverflow hard-earned points :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it myself, but I understand that's the idea behind http://jqtouch.com/

Comment: Yes, i saw that one and it looks great. I just found http://jquerymobile.com and am trying to figure out if this will help me in any way.